# Help with PCB Layout Validation

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication

My project consists of:

- DAQ device (USB1608-fs Plus: https://www.mccdaq.com/usb-data-acquisition/USB-1608FS-Plus-Series) which connects to my computer for data acquisition of up to 8 analog input channels (this device has pins for digital ground and analog ground which I assume must be grounded on my PCB to prevent an open circuit)
- A PCB I made that supplies 5V each, from the DAQ device, through a header pin, to 2 female TRS jacks mounted on this PCB. This board rests on top of the DAQ device by 2 header pins
- 2 female TRS jacks each with 3 contacts: GND, OUT, VCC
- Piezo sensors with male TRS jacks endings: GND, OUT, VCC
- Traces that I made on the PCB which receive signals from the OUT pads of the TRS and carries this to two separate channels on the DAQ device (I made traces for analog ground as well)

I'd like to validate the PCB that I made which has the **sole purpose of handling 5V supply to each of the female TRS jacks, grounding analog signals, and carrying analog data from the female TRS jacks to separate input channel pins for the DAQ device to take**. If anyone could confirm that my design is capable of these tasks without any problems, it would be greatly appreciated!!

In addition, this board will only be about 3"x3"x0.6mm with basic PCB materials and minimum quantity, from anyone's experiences with PCB fabrication services, what would the cost for this likely come down to? (I've been getting quotes for $1250, $300, ...)

Directly below is the PCB I designed:

- Pins 1 & 3 (bottom right corner) are analog input channels that connect to the DAQ device mounted below
- Pin 2 (bottom right corner) is analog ground
- Pin 20 (top right corner) is analog ground
- Pin 39 (top left corner) is the 5V supply coming from the DAQ device
- Pins outlined in green are poured into an internal plane for analog ground
- Pins outlined in red are poured into an internal plane for digital ground

[image: PCB Layout Top Layer]
[image: PCB Layout Bottom Layer]
[image: PCB Layers]
[image: PCB Schematic]
[image: Piezosensor of use]
[image: DAQ Device Pin Layout (P1-20 & P21-40)]

Comment: What line thickness are you using? I think you are eligible for $5 PCB service from PCBWay, JLC or similar.

Comment: There's no reason to make the traces so thin.

Comment: All traces are 10mils, what trace width would you recommend?

Comment: You are Designing in Altium, if you are new to PCB design, I would recommend Fedevel on youtube, he covers a LOT of topics, and uses Altium too, so you can get a lot of good pointers, especially when it comes to trace thickness. It all depends on currents, and how much noise control you want. There's other considerations like regulatory testing and self heating, but I would start with Fedevel. Also, why did you make this a 4 layer board? You could save a lot of money with a 2 layer in this case.

Comment: @JamesS I have edited the main post and updated the PCB layout and layers to a 2-layer board (top & bottom). I set the top plane as analog ground (top plane will also contain signal traces), the bottom plane as digital ground, and repoured across nets accordingly. Just on a final note, does the updated PCB appear correct?

Comment: What screw terminals are you using? I don’t know of any that have 0.1” spacing and 28 thou pins. I’d expect 0.2” spacing and something like a 60thou hole (1.5mm). A handy hint: there’s about 40 thou to a millimetre.